# Creating a geodatabase

Tags: arcmap, esri-geodatabase

I am new to GIS .
I would like to create a geodatabase in ArcGIS that stores information about different regions in a country. In each region there are few villages that are selected to monitor their  land cover change by taking images (jpeg) of those sites every 2 years. The database should have all the images taken each two years and different features found in that region such as services ( roads, rivers and villages). It should be able to add new information every two years.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. We are not a tutorial site. Questions here are expected to describe a concrete problem, and show effort towards solving that problem.

Comment: You have explained what you want to do, but you have not asked a question. My guess is you want a complete set of details on how to get your database set up. Lots of helpful folks around here, but generally you get responses to questions asking for help to get over a hurdle while you are experimenting  in the process of working out a solution to your problem. What you are asking is not very hard at the new user level. You can get started [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/create-file-geodatabase.htm) and then ask question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very broad question that could really be answered a number of ways, but check out this post from Esri on [creating file geodatabases](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/create-file-geodatabase.htm) to get your research started. In your case, you will want to use a file geodatabase (.gdb) since you will be attaching photos. Personal geodatabases (.mdb) have a 2GB limit. When you get to the point of determining which feature classes (layers) or tables that you want to attach photos to, be sure to [enable attachments](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-attributes/enabling-attachments-on-a-feature-class.htm) on those layers.